# Combining attributes from multiple point shapefiles using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-joins

I have seven point shapefiles with the same points (number and location) but different attributes. I would like to collapse all the attributes to a single point shapefile. I know that if I had only two, in QGIS I could simply join attributes by location.

Is it possible to perform the operation without manually operating it 7 times?

Comment: Use the merge tool to combine all shapefiles then use the delete duplicate geometries tool.

Comment: Wouldn't I just end up with one attribute per point this way?

Comment: Indeed the suggestion you propose is not effective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems that the quickest solution is Python-based:

```
iter1 = general.runalg('qgis:joinattributesbylocation', Points, Points_2,['equals'],0,0,"",0, r"\iter1.shp")
iter2 = general.runalg('qgis:joinattributesbylocation', r"\iter1.shp",Points_3,['equals'],0,0,"",0, r"\iter2.shp")
```

and so on...